# Chistofides' algorithm for the traveling salesman problem with relaxed triangle inequality

Tags: algorithms, graphs, algorithm-analysis, approximation, traveling-salesman

It is known that Christofides’ algorithm returns a 3/2-approximation for the traveling salesman problem given a complete graph $G$ such that distances obey the triangle inequality. Suppose that we weaken the triangle inequality to the setting where distances obey the guarantee that for each triple $i, j, l \in V$  it is the case that $d_{ij} + d_{jl} \geq d_{il}/c$ where $c \geq 1$. How do I then express the approximation ratio in terms of $c$? To do this, I think I have to find the cost of the shortcutted tour of $G$ that visits each node in the set of nodes with odd degree $O$. I know that if the distance just obeyed the normal triangle inequality, then this shortcut tour on $O$ would at most be the cost of the whole tour of $G$. But what is the cost when distances only obey the relaxed triangle inequality?

Comment: I think the approximation guarantee can blow to $O(c^{\log n})$ for Christofides algorithm, where $n$ are number of vertices in the graph. Obtaining it is easy. Are you looking for a better guarantee?

Comment: You may want to see [Section 2 of this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/S0895480192240226?casa_token=cIdSby0_3kcAAAAA:SmrkkE0soIh5t7o_1JQf_i7_zA7kw9Xo4Xf0kWdKkFi8c9bCl12bq73v0qdtpERNvTre4r7sEQ) as well.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami I wonder if it is possible to get an approximation factor of 3c/2

Comment: That is an open problem. [This](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S002001901500099X) is one of the recent paper that studies this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get a bound of OPT + 0.5C * OPT assuming that the cost of the MST is less or equal than OPT and that the cost of the perfect matching is at most 0.5C * OPT which can done by constructing a tour in the set of odd degree vertices by shortcutting the general optimal tour.